# интернационализация посредством ResourceBundle и Locale

Tags: java, javafx, ui, locale, интернационализация

Есть простенький класс с интерфейсом:

```
public class JavaFXApplication25 extends Application {
    String txt = "Say Hello";
    String txt2 = "Hello World!";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button(txt);
        Label lbl = new Label();
        Button changeLang = new Button("Изменить язык");

        btn.setOnAction(ev -> {
            lbl.setText(txt2);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn,lbl,changeLang);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

нужно посредством ResourceBundle и Locale сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Изменить язык" строка "Hello World!" заменялась на "Привет мир!" а строка "Say Hello" на строку "Сказать привет" при условии что соответствующие файлы *.properties уже существуют с нужными строками. Другими словами нужно поменять язык интерфейса. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Подскажите какой командой переключатся между файлами *.properties

Comment: Если необходимо, поля и методы в классе можно добавлять/переставлять/менять.

Comment: ResourceBundle в первую очередь используется с контроллерами и FXML. А тут разворачивать что-либо просто обессмыслено. (код реализации будет размером с ваш пример) Вот например статья http://crypto.pp.ua/2010/06/internacionalizaciya-teksta-java/

Comment: [Отметьте ответ верным, получите +2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/291565)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так

```
public class Solution extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    initialize(primaryStage, getResourceBundle(Locale.ENGLISH));
}

private void initialize(Stage stage, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    Button changeLang = new Button(resourceBundle.getString("button"));

    Button btn = new Button(resourceBundle.getString("change-language-button"));
    btn.setOnAction(ev -> {
        stage.close();
        initialize(stage, getResourceBundle(new Locale("ru")));
    });

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, lbl, changeLang);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    stage.setTitle(resourceBundle.getString("title"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

private ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
    return ResourceBundle.getBundle("LangBundle", locale);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```